# Prove specific decision problem is NP-complete

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

- Given: graph G
- Input: k
- Return: "YES" if there exists a set of k nodes, such that no two nodes are connected and no two nodes are connected to the same node. For example if (A,B) and (B,C) then A and C are not allowed in the set of k nodes.
  How would we prove this problem is NP-complete?

EDIT: I imagine we could use Independent Set/Vertex Cover?

Comment: Looks like if you complement the graph your are looking for cliques of size k at least... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801138/find-all-complete-sub-graphs-within-a-graph

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (?) this is a homework problem.

As a hint, start with the [dominating set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).